# Google Maps - Secure the value of the LatLng

Tags: c#, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to secure the values of LatLng that are used to draw lines on a Google Map since I have some work that I did and I don't want anybody to copy it ..

Are the points used to draw the lines visible to anyone to see it and copy it or it is eventually secured?

I draw the Lines in the success function of an ajax call:

```
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(x, y);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 11,
            center: position,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(
            document.getElementById("googlemap"),
            myOptions);

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url: url,
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function () {
                    $.each(this, function (index, Segment) {
                        $.each(Segment, function () {
                            for (var i = 0; i < Segment.X.length - 1; i++) {
                                var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
                                    path: [new google.maps.LatLng(Segment.Y[i], Segment.X[i]), new google.maps.LatLng(Segment.Y[i + 1], Segment.X[i + 1])],
                                    strokeColor: color,
                                    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                                    strokeWeight: 2,
                                    map: map
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
            }
        });
```

So is the point copyable for the fact that it is drawn in the client side ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't secure the points as long as you render the line on clientSide.  As soon as you create a polyline this polyline is accessible and the path can be retrieved(no matter if you encrypt the JSON somehow).

The only approach I see so far is a serverside rendering, e.g. an image containing the line as overlay or a FusionTableLayer(created from a fusionTable with private access)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, client-side code is by its nature insecure and copyable.  For instance you make an AJAX request for a specific URL, which will return some JSON with a series of points.  If someone else accessed that URL directly, they'd be able to get the points from that same JSON.

Comment: So in my case how could I secure the json file so that only me can get the results